# What does 'mining' means in smart contract ?

Tags: blockchain, mining, smartcontracts

I just would like to check my understanding.

In Bitcoin platform, the miner who does the following:
- verify each unconfirmed transaction.
- group them in a block 
- hash the block and find the nonce ( proof of work )

Now, in Ethereum platform, who is the minor ? does the node which call a function in the  smart contract can be called ( minor ) ??

If yes, what is the name of parties who call a smart contract function to follow the contract ??

Now I have coded a smart contract to set the prices between parties, each party has to call the function in the smart contract with goods amounts  and the contract will calculate the settlement.

Each party has to pay gas to execute this call. Who will get this fees, EVM ( as a fees of  call execution ) ???

and does the gas amount changes based on the amount of data in the call ( as a parameter )  or on the code complexity??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Proof of Work is the consensus algorithm that is used in Bitcoin. Each implementation of Blockchain has its own consensus algorithm.

The purpose of the consensus algorithms is to allow an update the state of the transactions according to specific rules, where the rights to apply the rules are distributed among a certain number of nodes. The necessary number of nodes is determined by the set of users with the right to make decisions according to a consensus algorithm.

Ethereum

- The consensus algorithm: [Proof of stake](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ)
- The minors of Bitcoin are the validators of Ethereum. Validators are randomly assigned the right to propose blocks.

Hyperledger:

- The consensus algorithm: [PBFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710738/pbft-algorithm-in-hyperledger)
- The Peers will call the smart contract